# Add Cube Shape Style to Android button

Tags: android, android-studio, styles, mobile-devices, cubes

I am trying to create a cube shape for my button like the one on this site:
http://mycolorscreen.com/2014/12/03/cubes-8/

I can't seem to get much to work besides changing the color. Is it possible to add styles to make my button look like this cube shape? Does anyone know a good resource for learning to make styles like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to create a cube image, this can easily be made on the program paint.net, save the image and put it in your drawable folder. then set the image to a button.

I quickly created an example you are free to use if needed. (note i did no size tests)

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want. It looks a little goofy, but I'm sure I can go from here and get it working the way I like. Thank you for the help!